# Bukkit Plugin: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

So I'm trying to load this new plugin I made and I've searched everything but I can't find the error! Please help, this is taking for ever.

This is my main class:

```
package com.hugcraft.hugkitpvp;


import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.block.Sign;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.block.SignChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class HugKitPvP extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {


private InventoryMenuManager invmenu;

public void onEnable() {
    invmenu = new InventoryMenuManager(this);
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

    @EventHandler     
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if (!(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) return;
    if (e.getClickedBlock().getState() instanceof Sign) {
        Sign s = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
        if (s.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("§3[Kits]")) {
            invmenu.show(e.getPlayer());

        }
    }
}

        @EventHandler
        public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e) {
            if (e.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[Kits]")) {
                e.setLine(0, "§b[Kit]");
                e.setLine(1, "§3Click Here");
                e.setLine(2, "§3To Choose");
                e.setLine(3, "§3Your Kit!");
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Listener Class:

```
package com.hugcraft.hugkitpvp;



import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.LeatherArmorMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

public class InventoryMenuManager implements Listener {

private Inventory inv;
private ItemStack w, ww, s, pp, sb, a, t, c, r;

public InventoryMenuManager(Plugin ppp) {
    inv = Bukkit.getServer().createInventory(null, 9, "Choose your kit!");


    w = createItem(Material.IRON_SWORD, ChatColor.GREEN + "Warrior");
    ww = createItem(Material.STICK, ChatColor.BLUE + "Wizard");
    s = createItem(Material.NETHER_STAR, ChatColor.YELLOW + "Ninja");
    pp = createItem(Material.FIRE, ChatColor.RED + "Pyro");
    sb = createItem(Material.SNOW_BALL, ChatColor.GRAY + "Demoman");
    a = createItem(Material.BOW, ChatColor.AQUA + "Archer");
    t = createItem(Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE, ChatColor.WHITE + "Tank");
    c = createItem(Material.ENDER_PEARL, ChatColor.BLACK + "Chicken");
    r = createItem(Material.GOLD_BOOTS, ChatColor.GREEN + "Runner");

    inv.setItem(1, w);
    inv.setItem(2, ww);
    inv.setItem(3, s);
    inv.setItem(4, pp);
    inv.setItem(5, sb);
    inv.setItem(6, a);
    inv.setItem(7, t);
    inv.setItem(8, c);
    inv.setItem(9, r);

    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, ppp);

}

private ItemStack createItem(Material dc, String name ) {
    ItemStack i = new ItemStack(dc);
    ItemMeta im = i.getItemMeta();
    im.setDisplayName(name);
    im.setLore(Arrays.asList("Choose kit " + name.toLowerCase() + "!"));
    i.setItemMeta(im);
    return i;


}

public void show(Player p) {
    p.openInventory(inv);
}

Player p;
PlayerInventory pi = p.getInventory();



//Warrior Kit
@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
    if (!e.getInventory().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(inv.getName())) return;
    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta() == null) return;
    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Warrior")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();

        //Wizard Kit
        }
    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Wizard")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
         e.getWhoClicked(); {
             ItemStack stick = new ItemStack(Material.STICK, 1);
             stick.addUnsafeEnchantment(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 5);
         }
         e.getWhoClicked(); {
             ItemStack wand = new ItemStack(Material.BLAZE_ROD, 1);
             wand.addUnsafeEnchantment(Enchantment.FIRE_ASPECT, 1);
         }
            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack helmet = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) helmet.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Wizard Helmet");
                meta.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
                pi.setHelmet(helmet);
                helmet.setItemMeta(meta);
            }
            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack cp = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) cp.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Wizard Chestplate");
                meta.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
                pi.setChestplate(cp);
                cp.setItemMeta(meta);
            }
            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack legs = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) legs.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Wizard Leggings");
                meta.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
                pi.setLeggings(legs);
                legs.setItemMeta(meta);
            }
            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack boots = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) boots.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Wizard Leggings");
                meta.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
                pi.setBoots(boots);
                boots.setItemMeta(meta);
            }
            e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();

        //Ninja Kit
    }
    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Ninja")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
         e.getWhoClicked(); {
             ItemStack sword = new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD, 1);
             sword.addUnsafeEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 1);
         }
            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack nc = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) nc.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.BLACK + "Ninja Chestplate");
                meta.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                pi.setChestplate(nc);
                nc.setItemMeta(meta);
            }

            e.getWhoClicked(); {
                ItemStack nl = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS, 1);
                LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) nl.getItemMeta();
                meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Ninja Leggings");
                meta.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                pi.setLeggings(nl);
                nl.setItemMeta(meta);
            }
            e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();


        //Pyro Kit
    }
    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Pyro")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack sword = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_SWORD, 1);
            sword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.FIRE_ASPECT, 1);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_BOOTS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();

        //Demoman Kit
    }

    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Demoman")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_BOOTS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.SNOW_BALL, 10));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();


        //Archer Kit
    }

    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Archer")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_SWORD));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.BOW));
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack ah = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET, 1);
            LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) ah.getItemMeta();
            meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Archer Helmet");
            meta.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            pi.setHelmet(ah);
            ah.setItemMeta(meta);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack ac = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE, 1);
            LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) ac.getItemMeta();
            meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Archer Chestplate");
            meta.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            pi.setChestplate(ac);
            ac.setItemMeta(meta);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack al = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS, 1);
            LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) al.getItemMeta();
            meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Archer Leggings");
            meta.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            pi.setLeggings(al);
            al.setItemMeta(meta);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack ab = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, 1);
            LeatherArmorMeta meta = (LeatherArmorMeta) ab.getItemMeta();
            meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Archer Boots");
            meta.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            pi.setLeggings(ab);
            ab.setItemMeta(meta);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.ARROW, 32));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();


        //Tank Kit
    }

    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Tank")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_HELMET, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_LEGGINGS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BOOTS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();


        //Chicken Kit
    }

    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Chicken")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, 1));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.ENDER_PEARL, 10));
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();


        //Runner Kit
    }

    if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Runner")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD));
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            ItemStack rb = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS);
            rb.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
        }
        e.getWhoClicked(); {
            p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 100000, 2));
        }
        e.getWhoClicked();pi.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 8));
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();

      }
   }
}
```

Hopefully I can fix this as fast as possible.
Thank You If You Answer.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace tells you were the error is, which turns a whole wall of code  (which we have before us) into a small piece.  It'd benefit you and us if you posted the stack trace, as many of us don't have the ability to run your code, but we can tease out reasons why you're getting the NPE.

Comment: add exception handling code to print the stack trace; at the very least should be something like `try {/*code*/} catch(Exception ex) { System.err.println(e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(System.err);}`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error is:

```
public void show(Player p) {
    p.openInventory(inv);
}

Player p; //<<<<< HERE
PlayerInventory pi = p.getInventory();
```

The `Player` p is never initialized, so it defaults to null. You get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call a method on a null `Object`, so, you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to run `p.getInventory()`, which is effectively `null.getInventory()`, which throws a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you should initialize `p`:

```
Player p;
public void show(Player pl){
    p = pl; //p is no longer null, unless the method show(null) is called, otherwise, you're good to go!
    pl.openInventory(inv);
}

PlayerInventory pi = p.getInventory();
```